# Update access database with openrowset

Tags: vb6

In my vb6 program I use Sql2008 R2 database. In one part of program I must update table in access database and I try this :

```
conSql.Execute ("update TmpIst set TmpIst.Nalaz = '+' from openrowset('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','d:\pregledi\pregledi2015.mdb';'Admin';'','select from nalazi where protokol = 'B-07-15'') as TmpIst")
```

but I have problem with apostrophes in select expression. How to pass string condition in this or others similar examples.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're escaping the single quotes used to wrap your criteria value

**Try changing:**

```
'B-07-15''
```

**to this**

```
''B-07-15'''
```